# CFD implementation in software

Tags: finite-element, finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, simulation

I've been learning CFD theory for 4 months (which includes FEA, FDM AND FVM) and now I want to start running simulations. As a novice to CFD software, I would appreciate some advice on where to start, e.g., OpenFoam, Matlab, Fortran? (I am comfortable with programming and learning coding languages).

Comment: This is a very general and objective question. I would recommend writing a simple one or two dimensional FVM code in Matlab for a classic CFD problem and once you're comfortable, move onto OpenFoam. Go through some of the examples in OpenFoam and then again, try to solve a classic CFD problem.

Comment: If you want to try your hands on software, this video could be a decent start
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2u1j0b5nKwA